# Is there a formula to extract specific characters from a box in Google Sheets?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have 6 columns and 4 rows like:

```
A B C D E F,  A B C D,  A B C, A B C D E
```

now I want my end data like:

```
A>B>C>D>E>F,  A>B>C>D,  A>B>C,  A>B>C>D>E
```

I have used concatenate formula, but getting a result like:

```
A>B>C>D>E>F,  A>B>C>D>,  A>B>C>>,  A>B>C>D>E>
```

Here I don't want `>>` character when there is no data available in the column
I have tried

```
=Concatenate(A,">",B,">",C,">",D,">",E,">",F)
```

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways how to solve it like using `REGEXREPLACE` or `SUBSTITUTE`:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A12, ">>", ">")
```

---

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A12, ">>", ">")
```

[image: 0]

or `IF` statement like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:F1<>"", A1:F1&">", ))
```

[image: 0]

```
=JOIN( , ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:F1<>"", A1:F1&">", )))
```

[image: 0]

---

or perhaps simple `TEXTJOIN`

```
=TEXTJOIN(">", 1, A1:F1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: TEXTJOIN worked for my issue. Thank you very much :) Next time I will provide a screenshot also

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUBSTITUTE(CONCATENATE(D1,">",E1,">",F1,">",G1,">",H1), ">>", ">")
```

[image]

Comment: It worked to replace >> as >. Thanks for your suggestion. Learned something new :)